# SVG Camera Pan - Translate keeps resetting to 0 evertime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, svg

Well i have this SVG canvas element, i've got to the point so far that once a user clicks and drags the canvas is moved about and off-screen elements become on screen etc....

However i have this is issue in which when ever the user then goes and click and drags again then the translate co-ords reset to 0, which makes the canvas jump back to 0,0.

Here is the code that i've Got for those of you whio don't wanna use JS fiddle

Here is the JSfiddle demo - https://jsfiddle.net/2cu2jvbp/2/

edit: Got the solution - here is a JSfiddle DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/hsqnzh5w/

Any and all sugesstion will really help.

```
var states = '',  stateOrigin;
var root = document.getElementById("svgCanvas");
var viewport = root.getElementById("viewport");
var storeCo =[];

function setAttributes(element, attribute)
{
    for(var n in attribute) //rool through all attributes that have been created.
    {
     element.setAttributeNS(null, n, attribute[n]);   
    }
}

function setupEventHandlers() //self explanatory;
{
  setAttributes(root, {
      "onmousedown": "mouseDown(evt)", //do function
      "onmouseup": "mouseUp(evt)",
      "onmousemove":  "mouseMove(evt)", 
  }); 
}

setupEventHandlers();


function setTranslate(element, x,y,scale) {
    var m = "translate(" + x + "," + y+")"+  "scale"+"("+scale+")";

      element.setAttribute("transform", m);
}


function getMousePoint(evt) { //this creates an SVG point object with the co-ords of where the mouse has been clicked.
    var points = root.createSVGPoint();

    points.x = evt.clientX;
    points.Y = evt.clientY;

    return points;
}


function mouseDown(evt)
{
    var value;
    if(evt.target == root || viewport)
    {
     states = "pan";   
     stateOrigin = getMousePoint(evt);
        console.log(value);
    }   
}

function mouseMove(evt)
{
    var pointsLive = getMousePoint(evt);

    if(states == "pan")
    {
     setTranslate(viewport,pointsLive.x - stateOrigin.x, pointsLive.Y - stateOrigin.Y, 1.0); //is this re-intializing every turn?
     storeCo[0] = pointsLive.x - stateOrigin.x
     storeCo[1] = pointsLive.Y - stateOrigin.Y;
    }

    else if(states == "store")
    {
        setTranslate(viewport,storeCo[0],storeCo[1],1); // store the co-ords!!!
        stateOrigin = pointsLive; //replaces the old stateOrigin with the new state
        states = "stop";
    }
}

function mouseUp(evt)
{
    if(states == "pan")
    {
     states = "store"; 
        if(states == "stop")
        {
         states ='';   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your mousedown function, you are not accounting for the fact that the element might already have a transform and you are just overwriting it.

You are going to need to either look for, and parse, any existing transform.  Or an easier approach would be to keep a record of the old x and y offsets and when a new mousedown happens add them to the new offset.

Comment: what dyou mean by adding the off-set?